# NHibernate MappingException: persistent class TodoLog not found

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

I have two classes `Todo` and `TodoLog` that I have created mapping for and some unittests for their respective constructors.
When I run these tests I receive the error `Could not load type TodoLog. Possible cause no assembly name specified` with the innerexception `MappingException: persistent class TodoLog not found`.
The error always refers to `TodoLog` even when I run the test for the `Todo` constructor.
The mapping for both classes are rather straightforward.

Mapping for `Todo`:

```
[Class(NameType = typeof()Todo, Table = "Todo")]
public class Todo
{
    [Id(-2, Name = "Id")]
    [Generator(-1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual Guid TodoGuid { get; set; }

    private IList<TodoLog> logs = new List<TodoLog>();
    [Bag(0, Name = "Logs", Table = "TodoLog", Inverse = true)]
    [Key(1, Column = "Todo")]
    [OneToMany(2, ClassType = typeof(TodoLog)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<TodoLog> Logs
    {
        get => logs;
        protected set => log = (IList<TodoLog>)value;
    }
}
```

Mapping for `TodoLog`

```
[Class(NameType = typeof(TodoLog), Name = "TodoLog")]
public class TodoLog
{
    [Id(-2, Name = "Id")]
    [Generator(-1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public virtual Todo Todo { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual Enums.TodoAction Action { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public virtual User ExecutedBy { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual DateTime ExectutedOn { get; set; }
}
```

======== EDIT ========

When I put all the code of `TodoLog` in comment the tests run fine but as soon as I add the `Class`-attribute to `TodoLog` I receive the same error as before. Removing `TodoLog` completely and adding a different class `TodoTest` results in the same error for `TodoTest`.
I have also used .Net Reflector to check wether that class compiled correctly but everything seems fine there.

When debugging the code when I run the test the error occurs loading the assembly which contains `TodoLog`:

```
foreach(var a in projectsAssemblies)
{
    Configuration.AddInputStream(HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(a));
}
```

When viewing the property `ExportedTypes` of the assembly which contains `TodoLog` the `TodoLog` class is in that list.

Comment: Can you show how you're building your `SessionFactory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, I'd say, would be in the doubled **NAME** mapping:

```
[Class(NameType = typeof(TodoLog), Name = "TodoLog")]
```

We should use either

1. `NameType` or
2. `Name`

Because as we can see in the ([source](https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes/blob/master/src/NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes/ClassAttribute.cs#L131)) - `NameType` is at the end filling the `Name`:

```
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._name;
        }
        set
        {
            this._name = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary> </summary>
    public virtual System.Type NameType
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Type.GetType( this.Name );
        }
        set
        {
            if(value.Assembly == typeof(int).Assembly)
                this.Name = value.FullName.Substring(7);
            else
                this.Name = HbmWriterHelper.GetNameWithAssembly(value);
        }
    }
```

So, where is the problem?

While in the `Log` mapping we use just **`NameType`**

```
[Class(NameType = typeof()Todo, Table = "Todo")]
```

the value of the **Name** is correct... meaning, with **full name**

```
Name = "MyNamespace.TodoLog, MyAssembly"
```

while int `TodoLog` ..

```
Name = "TodoLog"
```

And that is the source of the exception:

> Could not load type `TodoLog`.
>
> MappingException: persistent class `TodoLog` not found

Because we need **`MyNamespace.TodoLog, MyAssembly`**

> NOTE: mostlikely the `Name` should have been `Table`
> *`[Class(NameType = typeof(TodoLog), Table = "TodoLog")]`*

Comment: You are correct changing the `Class` attribute to `[Class(NameType = typeof(TodoLog), Table = "TodoLog")]` solved my issue!

Comment: Great to see that, sir. Enjoy NHibernate